# How to take bulk inputs in python using input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

Code as following:

```
#enter code here
source_input = input("enter source url: ")
destination_input = input("enter the destination url: ")
new_source = source_input.replace("https://www.domain.com.au","")
new_destination = destination_input.replace("https://www.domain.com.au","")
symbol = "=>" 
symbol_space = len(symbol)
center = symbol.center(symbol_space)
source_final = f" '{new_source}' "
destination_final = f" '{new_destination}' " 
print(source_final+center+destination_final)
```

but this code is not taking multiline inputs. I want to provide multiple source and destination inputs like:

```
Actual source input
https://www.domain.com.au/shop

Actual destination input
https://www.domain.com.au/shopwithus

Actual output
'/shop' => '/shopwithus'


desired source inputs to be taken
https://www.domain.com.au/shop
https://www.domain.com.au/main    
https://www.domain.com.au/home
https://www.domain.com.au/contactus

desired destiantion inputs to be taken
https://www.domain.com.au/shopwithus
https://www.domain.com.au/gomain    
https://www.domain.com.au/homemain
https://www.domain.com.au/contactus

Desired outputs

 '/shop' => '/shopwithus'
 '/main' => '/gomain'
 '/home' => 'homemain'
 '/contactus' => '/contactus'
```

is there any way to achieve this kind of inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a lateral move but you could use command line arguments with `argparse`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-s', '--source', help='The source.', required=True, type=str)
parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', help='The desitnation.', required=True, type=str)
cmd_args = parser.parse_args()


def main() -> None:
    print("source     :", cmd_args.source)
    print("destination:", cmd_args.destination)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then when executing just specify the arguments like follows (to script is called `tmp.py`)

```
python3 tmp.py -s "www.source.com" -d "www.destination.com"
# source     : www.source.com
# destination: www.destination.com
```

Comment: Hi @niko thanks for answering but the desired output need to be in `'/shop' => '/shopwithus' '/shop' => '/shopwithus'
 '/main' => '/gomain'
 '/home' => 'homemain'
 '/contactus' => '/contactus'` this format even though. by taking bulk inputs